# Looking for a way to create a mapping from `app.example.com` to actually load `example.com/app`

Tags: amazon-web-services

Is there a way on AWS to create mapping from `app.example.com` to actually load `example.com/app`. I have tried to create a CNAME but it doesnt seem to allow the `/app`

Comment: No, DNS is unaware of paths.  Are you saying if someone goes to `app.example.com`, you just want a browser redirect to change their address bar to `example.com/app` and then load that page? Or something else?

Comment: It is more about proxying the request. I want to be able to create a CNAME `app.example.com` for a domain `app.herokuapp.com`. But I also want to permanently attach something to every request to `app.herokuapp.com` i.e i want `app.example.com` to proxy to `app.herokuapp.com/appId`. Alternatively it would be find to attach a permanent header with the appId

Comment: Just a little more clarification/less abstraction and I think we'll be able to nail this down.  You want something like `https://my-handy-app.example.com/${path}` to actually request  `https://serene-example-4269.herokuapp.com/some-static-value-added-here/${path}`...correct?

Comment: correct. In my use case the ${path} is actually a token - which is why it would also be fine to pass it in as a header attached to all requests. After some further experimenting I seem to have been able to achieve this by creating a cloudfront distribution in front of the herokuapp. Are there any alternative methods that spring to mind?

Comment: No, actually... CloudFront was exactly what I was going to propose as a solution.  It allows insertion of custom origin request headers as well as static path-prepending via the "origin path" setting.

Comment: good to know, thank you :)